# Rspec test association with change matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have a model `User` that updates a global role (from Rolify) with an `after_save` callback.  I'm trying to test that the user's `Permission`s (a db view) are preserved when a global role is changed.  Currently all roles are reset when a global role is changed.

Ahead of putting my fix in, I'm trying to get a failing test result using `change` matchers, but this test is passing.

```
it "preserves permissions when changing role" do
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user, role: Role::ROLE_ADMIN)
  project = FactoryBot.create(:project)
  user.add_role :owner, project
  user.role = Role::ROLE_EDITOR
  expect { user.save; user.reload }.to_not change { user.permissions }
```

If I write the test as below, it fails (what I want), but it seems verbose.

```
it "preserves permissions when changing role" do
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user, role: Role::ROLE_ADMIN)
  project = FactoryBot.create(:project)
  user.add_role :owner, project
  permissions = Array.new user.permissions
  user.role = Role::ROLE_EDITOR
  user.save
  user.reload
  expect(user.permissions).to eq permissions
end
```

How can I test the change in association through an `after_save` callback using Rspec `change` matchers?

The model methods that change a user's role are below.  `sync_pending_role!` is what is run in the `after_save` callback.

```
def role=(new_role)
  @pending_role = new_role.to_s
end

def sync_pending_role!
  return if pending_role.blank?

  roles_to_remove = Role::ALLOWED_ROLES.without(pending_role.to_s)
  roles_to_remove.each { |role| remove_role role }

  add_role pending_role
end
```

Comment: can you check if `expect { user.save }.to_not change { user.reload.permissions }` works for you?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too with no luck

Comment: what if you did `expect { user.add_role :owner, project; user.role = Role::ROLE_EDITOR; user.save}.not_to change { user.reload.permissions }` (I'm guessing here, because IDK what;s in add_role and role= methods)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried that too